# How to use <DllImport> in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, dllimport

How should I DLLImport things in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)? An example would be:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer

End Function
```

If I put it inside a Class or somewhere else, I get "DLLimport is not defined" I am using [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008) Professional

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have to add `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices` to the top of your source file.

Alternatively, you can fully qualify attribute name:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropService.DllImport("user32.dll", _
    SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
```

Comment: Do you have any book for Visual basic 2015 which only talks about how to use any type of `System.Runtime.InteropService.DllImport` to become master on it?

Answer (score 8):

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this has already been answered, but here is an example for the people who are trying to use SQL Server Types in a vb project:

```
            Imports System
            Imports System.IO
            Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

            Namespace SqlServerTypes
                Public Class Utilities



                    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
                    Public Shared Function LoadLibrary(ByVal libname As String) As IntPtr

                    End Function

                    Public Shared Sub LoadNativeAssemblies(ByVal rootApplicationPath As String)
                        Dim nativeBinaryPath = If(IntPtr.Size > 4, Path.Combine(rootApplicationPath, "SqlServerTypes\x64\"), Path.Combine(rootApplicationPath, "SqlServerTypes\x86\"))
                        LoadNativeAssembly(nativeBinaryPath, "msvcr120.dll")
                        LoadNativeAssembly(nativeBinaryPath, "SqlServerSpatial140.dll")
                    End Sub

                    Private Shared Sub LoadNativeAssembly(ByVal nativeBinaryPath As String, ByVal assemblyName As String)
                        Dim path = System.IO.Path.Combine(nativeBinaryPath, assemblyName)
                        Dim ptr = LoadLibrary(path)

                        If ptr = IntPtr.Zero Then
                            Throw New Exception(String.Format("Error loading {0} (ErrorCode: {1})", assemblyName, Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()))
                        End If
                    End Sub
                End Class
            End Namespace
```

Comment: In retrospect, and sorry to somewhat hijack this thread although several of the questions and points are addressed by this code, it's main purpose is to get ReportViewer and SqlServerTypes to work in an old VB project, and that all worked. But I feel that a stubbed out LoadLibrary function that I believe should call into a kernel dll cannot be working correctly, and therefore ReportViewer may not have exercised that function.

Comment: I'm glad you did! I came to this while trying to do exactly what you posted. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I saw in *[getwindowtext (user32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowtext)* on pinvoke.net that you can place a `MarshalAs` statement to state that the StringBuffer is equivalent to LPSTR.

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Public Function GetWindowText(hwnd As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnManagedType.LPStr)>lpString As System.Text.StringBuilder, cch As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
```

I always use **Declare Function** instead of **DllImport**...
Its more simply, its shorter and does the same

Comment: There are a great number of things you *cannot* do with a Declare statement. None of the interop attributes are available to you. Honestly, this is legacy VB 6 syntax, and I think all new VB.NET code should be written using the standard .NET syntax.

Comment: Well, youre right but iam a lazy programmer, so i always try to get the shortest one :)
For my projects this one always helped me out