# How to cast an process instance into it's fitting object

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, process

maybe my question sounds very strange, but I want to do the following:

I have some instances of the Internet Explorer opened (iexplore.exe).
When I start my program, it should refresh all the instances of iexplore.exe without opening another instance of it.

In the beginning I thought it must be easy to refresh the Internet Explorer with help of a Visual Basic exe. But this thought was wrong.

No I was thinking about it and my thoughts where the following:

1. At runtime I have to find out all the processes iexplore.exe
2. I declare a variable `Dim Browsers() as WebBrowser`
3. Now I have to cast all processes iexplore.exe to the object list named Browsers.
4. With help of `Browsers.Refresh` it is easy to solve the Problem.

I have no idea how to do this and even not if this can work at all.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: If IE was written in .NET, you would have to get the process, get the form from that process, get the tab from the form, then get the WebBrowser from that tab. But I'm pretty sure it was not written in .NET so it wouldn't even have an instance of WebBrowser.

Comment: I understand what you mean and it sounds reasonable. But is there any other possibility to refresh existing instances from a vb.net program?

Comment: Maybe [C# using Sendkey function to send a key to another application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15292428/1115360), [How to use <DllImport> in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2229809/1115360), and [SendKeys.Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) will get you some way. N.B. the processname is "iexplore", i.e. there is no ".exe" on the end of it.